# python: GDAL raster output is distorted

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio, cell-size

I'm trying to understand why my multiband raster output created with GDAL is distorted.

**Short summary**: I got several hundreds of US counties data in csv format. For each one, I need to convert the CSV into a multiband raster. Each csv file have 24 columns, where the first two columns are X and Y UTM coordinates. For most of the counties, the script is running without issues. However, some counties have some barrier inlands which I suspects distorts margins of the raster.

I will provide the reproducible example along with the code I am using. I know is pretty a long code and I apologies for the size of the shapefile (that was the only I could find that had the same boundary with my raster), but is already been like several days since I trying to debug this. I tried `rasterio` as well and I got the same issue. Only `geocube` library was working properly but I would prefer not to use it.

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import random
import pandas as pd
from osgeo import gdal, osr
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from zipfile import ZipFile 

######## TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE, I WILL CREATE A GRID WITH POINTS AT 90 M EACH ############
# Download file from ESRI
url = (
       'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/715db3ed501b42fe9581caaa5c56caf9/data'
       )
filename = 'countyshapefiles.zip'
urlretrieve(url, filename) # the zip has a size of ~80 mb

# Unzip
with ZipFile('countyshapefiles.zip', 'r') as z:
    z.extractall(
        path = 'countyshapefiles'
    )

# Read the file
shapefile = r"countyshapefiles\USA_Counties.shp"
epsg = 32617

df = gpd.read_file(shapefile)
df = df.to_crs(f'EPSG:{epsg}')

df = df[(df['NAME'] == 'Hillsborough') & (df['STATE_NAME'] == 'Florida')] # this is the tricky county
df.plot()

# Extract the boundaries
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = df.total_bounds

# Set distance between points
spacing = 90 # in reality my data is at 30 m but for time/space saving purpose, I'll set it to 90.

# Get the coordinates
xcoords = [i for i in np.arange(xmin, xmax, spacing)]
ycoords = [i for i in np.arange(ymin, ymax, spacing)]

pointcoords = np.array(np.meshgrid(xcoords, ycoords)).T.reshape(-1, 2) #A 2D array like [[x1,y1], [x1,y2], ...
points = gpd.points_from_xy(x=pointcoords[:,0], y=pointcoords[:,1])
grid = gpd.GeoSeries(points, crs=df.crs)
grid.name = 'geometry'

# find points falling inside the poly
gridinside = gpd.sjoin(gpd.GeoDataFrame(grid), df[['geometry']], how="inner")

# Generate some random data
gridinside['variable1'] = gridinside.apply(lambda _: random.randint(0, len(gridinside.index)), axis=1)
gridinside['variable2'] = gridinside.apply(lambda _: random.randint(0, len(gridinside.index)), axis=1)


# Extract the X, Y coords
gdf = gridinside.get_coordinates(ignore_index=True)
gdf['var1'] = gdf.apply(lambda _: random.randint(0, len(gdf.index)), axis=1)
gdf['var2'] = gdf.apply(lambda _: random.randint(0, len(gdf.index)), axis=1)


######## LETS'S CREATE THE RASTER NOW ############
# Transform to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(gdf)

# Pivot the table 
dfP = df.pivot(index = 'y', columns='x', values=df.iloc[:, 2:4].columns)

# Get the width/height of the raster
height = df['y'].nunique()
width = df['x'].nunique()

# Create the bounds of the raster 
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = min(df['x']), min(df['y']), max(df['x']), max(df['y'])

# Specify the cell size
res_x = spacing
res_y = -spacing

# Output raster name
output_tif = '12057_fake_90m.tif'

# Create the dataset
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
dataset = driver.Create(output_tif, width, height, 2, gdal.GDT_Int16) # 2 bands
dataset.SetGeoTransform((xmin, res_x, 0, ymax, 0, res_y))

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)  # Set the projection
dataset.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

columns = df.iloc[:, 2: 4].columns
columns

# Write the data to the UTM raster bands
for i, column in enumerate(columns, start=1):
    band = dataset.GetRasterBand(i)
    column_data = np.array(dfP[column][::-1])
    column_data[np.isnan(column_data)] = -9999
    band.WriteArray(column_data)
    band.SetNoDataValue(-9999)
    band.SetDescription(column)
dataset = None
```

Comment: Rather than reinventing the wheel, why not just use basic gdal functionality? If the CSV XY values form a regular grid use `gdal.Translate` or if irregular, with `gdal.Grid`.  You may need to extract out just the X, Y and specific "Z" column from the CSV for each band.  Then clip to shapefile.

Comment: so `gdal.Translate` would avoid this whole part where I need to pivot the table? But thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the CSV XY values form a regular grid, you can treat the CSV as an [XYZ raster](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/xyz.html), though you will need to extract out just the X, Y and specific "Z" column from the CSV for each band that will form the multiband output. You can then clip to your shapefile with `gdal.Warp` and stack the clipped results.

```
import pandas as pd
from osgeo import gdal
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from zipfile import ZipFile

# # Download file from ESRI
# url = (
#        'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/715db3ed501b42fe9581caaa5c56caf9/data'
#        )
# filename = 'countyshapefiles.zip'
# urlretrieve(url, filename) # the zip has a size of ~80 mb
#
# # Unzip
# with ZipFile('countyshapefiles.zip', 'r') as z:
#     z.extractall(
#         path = 'countyshapefiles'
#     )

shapefile = r"countyshapefiles/USA_Counties.shp"
epsg = 32617
csvfile = "hill_multicolumn.csv"  # Assumes X, Y, col1,...,colN

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
df = df.sort_values(["Y", "X"], ascending=True)
vrts = []
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    df_col = df.filter(["X", "Y", col])
    df_col.to_csv(f"hill_{col}.csv", index=False)
    rds = gdal.OpenEx(f"hill_{col}.csv", gdal.OF_RASTER)
    vrt = gdal.Warp(
        f"/vsimem/hill_{col}.vrt",
        rds,
        cutlineDSName=shapefile,
        cutlineWhere="NAME = 'Hillsborough' AND STATE_NAME = 'Florida'",
        cropToCutline=True,
        srcSRS=f"EPSG:{epsg}"
    )
    vrts.append(vrt)

vrt = gdal.BuildVRT(f"/vsimem/hill.vrt", vrts, separate=True)
multiband = gdal.Translate("hill_multiband.tif", vrt)
```